# Prove that A is invertible if $A^2 - 4A -7I = 0$.

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

The $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ satisfies

$$A^2 - 4A -7I = 0,$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. Prove that $A$ is invertible.

I'm not sure how to do this. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $A(A-4I) = 7I$.

Comment: Not in characteristic $7$, though.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\left(\frac17(A-4I)\right)A=I
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** write $I = AA^{-1}$, so that: $$A^2-4A - 7AA^{-1} = 0.$$Can you solve for $A^{-1}$?

Comment: I'm still a little new to the concept of matrices. How exactly would I start to solve for A^-1

Comment: It's similar to real numbers, you only have to remember that not always matrices commute, and not always you can "divide" (i.e., multiply everything by the inverse). Here we would have: $$7AA^{-1} = A(A-4I) \implies AA^{-1} = \frac{1}{7}A(A-4I).$$ Since we assume that $A^{-1}$ exists, you can multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$ **by the left**, so we get only $A^{-1}$ on the left side. I'll let you finish it now.

Comment: ohh ok it makes sense now. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

you can rewrite $A^2 - 4A - 7I = 0$ as $$A\left(\frac17A-\frac47I\right) = I.$$  therefore $A$ is invertible and $$A^{-1} = \frac17A-\frac47I.  $$

Comment: Based on the level of the question, I think it's fair to assume the OP is working over the reals. Considerations of characteristics would be a needlessly high level of sophistication for the question, just as we don't worry about fields of characteristic 2 when teaching the quadratic equation.

Comment: @ZachEffman, i agree.  anyone who bothers with characteristic $7$ and the like is unlikely ask this question in the first place.